# Cannot start ruby on rails application on server but works locally, wrong environment path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I've encountered an issue that is preventing me from starting my Ruby on Rails application on our Production server despite it running correctly on both Development and Staging environments. The error message is as follows:

```
[ E 2021-04-26 14:53:39.4216 14896/T11 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /path/to/application: The application encountered the following error: No such file to load -- /path/to/application/app/config/environment.rb (LoadError)
```

For some reason Passenger is attempting to find the config/environment.rb inside of an app folder when instead it should just be looking for:

```
/path/to/application/config/environment.rb
```

Passenger is being configured using Apache and the site config can be seen below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
  # PassengerStartTimeout 90
  ServerAdmin email@example.com
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  DocumentRoot /path/to/application/public
  <Directory /path/to/application/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Multiviews
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

PassengerPreStart http://localhost
PassengerAppEnv production
PassengerLogFile ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/passenger.log
```

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04. I've included what I think are the relevant versions below:
Ruby - 2.5.1
Ruby on Rails - 5.2.5
Passenger - 6.0.7

Does anyone know what config I may be missing that is causing Passenger to be looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Can you run the server in production environment locally (without Passenger)?

Answer (score 0):

look .. i read about passenger , i am beginner to ruby ;"beginner"= when i remember about ruby,python i download them and i try to compile them to exe to find out if they changed things = .exe smaller or for the another alternative of compilers i usually use ..
today's test was in **ruby** + apache + php 8.1  as testing a output from a http://localhost/test/   *and without any compilation*   (**this isn't the answer to your question but if anyone needs this new point of view and you use php and ruby always ..**)

in windows with apache ,php ,..  and ruby installed , in your htdocs create test folder and put these into it:
**index.php**

```
<?php

// Highest priority
proc_nice(-20);

echo shell_exec('index.rb');
//system('index.rb');
?>
```

**index.rb**

```
#puts "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
puts "Hello World" + "<br>"

time1 = Time.new
puts "Current Time : " + time1.inspect + "<br>"

# Time.now is a synonym:
time2 = Time.now
puts "Current Time : " + time2.inspect + "<br>"
```

now open the browser and go to http://localhost/test/
then if you click refresh or you hit f5 key(refresh) in your bowser after the first results then the time shoul display the refresh values