# Ruby on Rail running apache show index of when accessing the site

Tags: ruby, apache, rake, bundler, rbenv

I have recently updated to Apache 2.4, and I am using Ruby on Rail to run my application. Following the upgrade, the site shows a content as seen in the image below, and the error on the log file shows this error message. I have tried using the 'Bundle Install' and checked the permission but that hasn't helped. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
[ 2022-02-07 07:47:24.5559 8104/7efc89c8f700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/adminuser/hroot: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: ba7e6074
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-RA01E9.html
  Message from application: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@hroot/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

[image]

```
             PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@hroot/wrappers/ruby
             SetEnv GEM_HOME /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This error shows a problem with the shared objects. You probably updated MySQL/MariaDB libraries with Apache and new libraries are incompatible with your mysql2 gem build. The solution is simple:

First, ensure you are using the `ruby-2.0.0-p353@hroot` RVM environment.

Then, execute the following command:

```
gem install mysql2 --version 0.3.14
```

This should rebuild your mysql2 gem for the new MySQL/MariaDB client libraries on your system.

Comment: thanks! I have set the RVM enviroment using 

``rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353@hroot --default`` then

``gem install mysql2 --version 0.3.14`` 

but still getting the same error message unfortuntely. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Everytime the server has been restarted the ruby version revert back to /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0):

this isn't the answer anyway but another method to run ruby (in my case Windows 10 ; if you use another OS try to find out how to  modify inside index.php  the ruby starter)
i post here an alternative method to use apache + php +...    and  ruby
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733656/5781320